# Qt Creator Community - Font Config

Tags: linux, fonts, qt

I've downloaded and installed the QtCreator (OpenSource Community edition).
It created a directory in my home called Qt.
I've a big screen and must all the fonts set to bigger.

All the Qt and Gtk system fonts are set to size 26, so all applications have bigger readable fonts, but QtCreator ignores the system font settings.

I edited the QtCreator Text Editor font to 26, but the other components have small fonts:

[image]

TextEditor fonts are readable, but eg. the file navigation menu is not readable.
I have searched for the fonts config, in the Qt directory in my home, that the QtCreator uses, but with no success.

How can I set the Font bigger?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so for now I found [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/127666/qtconfig-tool-for-qt-5). It is not completely a good solution, but it helps

```
~/Qt/Tools/QtCreator/bin/qtcreator -style=gtk
```

result:

[image]